# How to find how many items will fit into an object

Tags: geometry

So, for my Engineering Design class, we are incorporating more geometry and we have to solve this problem. We have to find out how many dice will fit into three different piñatas. One is a cube, one is shaped like and ice cream cone, and the other is shaped like a star. We have not been able to measure anything yet, but any sort of process I could use would be helpful. Thank you.

P.S. Feel free to ask any questions about information that is not clear.

Comment: I assume all the dice are identical cubes, and we can call the side of each cube $1$. I know how to describe the "cube" container; it has side $x\geq 1$ for some (not necessarily integer) $x$.  The cone I can take to be one with height $h$ directly above the center of the base circle of radius $r$. But what do you mean by "shaped like a star"? There are many star-like 3-D shapes; or perhaps you mean a shape whose cross-section for any value $0<z<h$ is a regular pentagram of side $x$?

Comment: @MohammadZuhairKhan: The answer is at least the one you gave, because you can make those dice into a smaller cube by regular packing.   But if $l$ is not a multiple of $d$, how do we know that there is no less-regular packing that takes advantage of the extra vloume to add one or more additional cubes?

Comment: See Fermi Problem https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermi_problem

Comment: By star, I mean like, it’s a 2D star with 5 points, like the most common pentagon with 5 triangles attached, and it is given a height, no round edges or anything. That’s the best I know how to describe it

Answer (score 2):

The problem of how many unit cubes can fit into a cube of side $x$, without further assumptions like "the dice are packed in the same orientation and are aligned so that all faces are either completely uncovered or completely covered by one face of another die," is quite hard and currently unresolved.

Let me illustrate the issue:  We are trying to fit unit dice into a cubic box of side $x=\frac{4+\sqrt{2}}2 \approx 2.71$.  The naive answer as given in a comment is that you can fit $2^3 = 8$ dice, because $\lfloor x \rfloor = 2$.  However, you can pack at least ten dice into that cube by making two layers of 5 dice each, with the bottom four corners of the 5 dice in the lower layer at
$$
\{ (0,0,0), (0,1,0) (1,1,0), (1,0,0)\} \\
\{ (x-1,0,0), (x-1,1,0) (x,1,0), (x,0,0) \} \\
\{(\frac12, 1-\frac{\sqrt{2}}4), ( 1-\frac{\sqrt{2}}4,\frac12,), (\frac12, 1+\frac{\sqrt{2}}4), ( 1-\frac{\sqrt{2}}4,\frac12)\\
\{ (0,x-1,0), (0,x,0) (1,x,0), (1,x-1,0) \} \\
\{ (x-1,x-1,0), (x-1,x,0) (x,x,0), (x,x-1,0) \} \\
$$
Even in this case, it would be hard to show that you can't jam an eleventh cube in by skewing them in a way that does not pack each set of cubes in a planar way.